# Is it possible using AZMS to authenticate users against Windows Azure AD?

Tags: azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory

Is it possible when using AZMS to authenticate users against a windows azure active directory tenant?

**EDIT**:  Actually I found the [AZMS intro page](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/mobile-services/) has this to say:

> Implementing an app-specific authentication system is of course supported, as is connecting to Windows Azure Active Directory for employee-facing mobile apps.

So a more specific question is can anyone point me to official guidance and code samples for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a very good solution to this question is to implement Auth0:

[Authenticate AZMS Apps with Auth0](http://blog.auth0.com/2013/03/17/Authenticate-Azure-Mobile-Services-apps-with-Everything-using-Auth0/)